# How to display List elements horizontally(using CSS probably) in a JQTouch toolbar div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqtouch

I have a `<div>` element, containing a  `<ul>`  with four `<li>` elements. What I need to do is set the `<li>` to display in horizontal orientation, and within the `<div>`. When I apply the JTouch class=toolbar to my `<div>`, what I see happening however is the the `<li>` elements do not even appear within the perimeter of the `<ul>` and both the `<ul>` and `<li>` seem to move outside of the parent `<div>`. How can I fix this situation please?

[Image of problem (Bottom right are the list elements instead of appearing within the div and ul)](http://i56.tinypic.com/2ivcg7q.jpg)

```
  <html>
    <head>

          <style type="text/css" media="screen">
                @import "../../jqtouch/jqtouch.css";
          </style>
          <style type="text/css" media="screen">
                @import "../../themes/apple/theme.css";
          </style>
          <script src="../../jqtouch/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
          <script src="../../jqtouch/jqtouch.js" type="application/x-javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
          <!-- 
               Tweet consumption in progress:
            -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="clock.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
          <!-- 
              Initialization:
            -->
          <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                $.jQTouch({
                      icon: 'icon.png',
                      startupScreen: 'img/startup.png'
                });
          </script>
          <style type="text/css">
                .toolbar2
                {
                      background: green;
                      height: 30;
                }
         #toolbarbottom ul li
        {
              display:inline;
              float: left;
              padding: 3px 5px;
        }
        #toolbarbottom ul
        {
              background-color: Green;
              background-color: Purple;
        }

          </style>
          <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                      var ulhtml = "<ul>";
                      $.getJSON("http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/AJEnglish.json?count=20&include_entities=true&callback=?", function (data) {
                            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                                  ulhtml += "<li class='arrow'>" + item.text + "</li>";
                            });
                            ulhtml += "</ul>";
                            $("#tweets").html(ulhtml);
                      });
                });
          </script>

    </head>
    <body>
          <div id="jqt">
                <div id="home">
                      <div id="toolbartop" class="toolbar">
                            <h2>
                                  Tweet </h2>
                            <a href="#add" class="button"> +</a>
                      </div>
                      <h2>
                            Most Recent Tweet</h2>
                      <div id="tweets">
                      </div>
                      <div id="toolbarbottom" class="toolbar" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;
                            width: 100%;">
     <div style="background-color:Black;"> 
                                  <ul  >
                                        <li id="active"><a id="current" href="#add" class="button">News</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#add" class="button">Updates</a> </li>
                                        <li><a href="#add" class="button">Contact Us</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#add" class="button">Website</a> </li>
                                  </ul>
     </div>

                      </div>
                       <div class="info">
                            This is a demo for jQTouch.
                      </div>
                </div>
                <div id="info">
                      <div class="toolbar">
                            <h1>
                                  About</h1>
                            <a href="#add" class="cancel">Cancel</a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="info">
                            This is a demo for jQTouch.
                      </div>
                </div>

          </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Float all li to left and give padding to them.

I implement it in html. Have a look and change accordingly in your code.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .toolbar ul li{float:left; padding:3px 5px;}
                    .toolbar ul {list-style-type:none;
    </style>
```

Comment: For some reason, that does not seem to work. See above code. I added the bit but the contents of the <li> remains to the far right of the page. Any other suggestions please?

Comment: That should work, coz I checked it on my side and it works fine. If it is not working there seem to be JQtouch issue.

Comment: Are you familiar with JTouch please? I copied over all my code for you to see please

Comment: Give us a link to a demo page or jsFiddle and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: The code is as above. I am not entirely sure how to set JQTouch up on Jsfiddle as I don't think there is a web link to the library except via download, but I have it set up at this link http://jsfiddle.net/znLtZ/ . Any help given will be appreciated

Comment: You can take a look at the JQtouch Demo page to see various files linked in to this

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.toolbar ul{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi Gabe, I tried that solution but that does not seem to fix the problem. I need the UL, and the LI elements to live inside of the DIV, and be displayed from left to right, but that doesn't seem to be happening. http://jsfiddle.net/kjb85/1/

Comment: I just noticed that I did not copy the piece where I have that particular correction made. But yes, the picture is of the page but the inline does not seem to be doing it.